# How do I find the angles for baseboard on an outside stair stringer?

Tags: trim, stairs, baseboard, cutting, angle

I'm installing baseboard on the outside of a staircase in my home. The staircase doesn't have an open stringer, and the height of my baseboard has created a really interesting angle at the bottom of the stairs where the floor meets the first riser.

[image: Outside Stringer Baseboard]

This cut has completely broken my brain. Any insight on how I can find the angles to wrap this around would be really appreciated!

Comment: (Whoa; it's kind of broken my brain, too.) A diagram showing the distances and angles would really help.

Answer (score 1):

From your picture, it looks like if you extend the non-flat sections of the moulding they'll intersect before you reach the vertical at the end of the stair (e.g., pardon my abysmal Photoshopping):

[image]

This would certainly be the easiest solution, although it may not be the prettiest one.

Comment: Looks good to me Daniel!

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to put a piece of blocking in to pull this out a bit, to avoid the long awkward angle (just because it would be *really* hard to get that cut perfectly).

[image]

You can use a piece of molding similar to the baseboard (different height maybe) or something more wood-grained to match the stairs.

Comment: That's it. Show up my Photoshop skills.

Comment: BTW, I like the way this will look a lot better than mine, although perhaps using a narrower piece of blocking would be the best solution.